# Why handle method does not fire during job execution?

Tags: laravel, queue, jobs

I have always used events and listeners to add tasks to the queue. Now I'm trying to use Jobs. I do it like this:
my job.

```
class eventJob implements ShouldQueue
{
     use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;
     public $message;
     /**
      * Create a new job instance.
      *
      * @return void
      */
     public function __construct($message)
     {
         $this->message = $message;
     }

     /**
      * Execute the job.
      *
      * @return void
      */
     public function handle()
     {
         Log::alert($this->message);
     }
}
```

My .env file: `QUEUE_CONNECTION=database`
In my controller, I dispatch the event like this:
`eventJob::dispatch('my message');`
A new record appears in the jobs table and to execute it I run `php artisan queue:work`
The record is removed from the jobs table, but nothing appears in the file logs

I tried in the handle method and the constructor to do `throw new \Exception("Error Processing the job", 1);` But nothing is written in the filed_jobs table, from which I made the assumption that the handle method and the constructor do not execute.
I also tried running my job like this:
`$job = new eventJob('my test message'); dispatch($job);`

But it does not change anything

Comment: Does the jobs table record data include the message you are trying to log?

Comment: Nope. It looks like this: ```{"uuid":"513f9aeb-e7a3-432c-bd4e-f618af829bc4","displayName":"App\\Jobs\\eventJob","job":"Illuminate\\Queue\\CallQueuedHandler@call","maxTries":null,"maxExceptions":null,"failOnTimeout":false,"backoff":null,"timeout":null,"retryUntil":null,"data":{"commandName":"App\\Jobs\\eventJob","command":"O:17:\"App\\Jobs\\eventJob\":0:{}"}}```

Comment: That suggests to me that `$message` is not getting set in your constructor. What is the content of `$message` when assigning it to `$this->message`?

Comment: I can't handle the ```$message``` in contructor. I tried ```Log::alert($message)``` and ```dd($message)``` but nothing happens

Comment: It looks correct to me. Can you dump the entire job class after constructing it? Also, try removing the `SerializesModels` trait since you aren't passing in any eloquent models.

Comment: I remove ```SerializesModels``` and do this in my controller 
```$job = eventJob::dispatch('my message');
 dd($job);```
It returns 
```#job: App\Jobs\eventJob^ {#1009
    +job: null
    +connection: null
    +queue: null
    +chainConnection: null
    +chainQueue: null
    +chainCatchCallbacks: null
    +delay: null
    +afterCommit: null
    +middleware: []
    +chained: []
  }
  #afterResponse: false
}```

Comment: I mean new up the job but don't dispatch it. Just dump the job to see if the class is being created with the message data. `$job = new eventJob('my message'); dd($job);` See if that looks right.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are asking to do like: ```$job = new eventJob('message'); dd($job);``` it returns the job class: ```App\Jobs\eventJob^ {#1010 // app/Console/Commands/Cron/CheckPaymentsStatus.php:41
  +job: null
  +connection: null
  +queue: null
  +chainConnection: null
  +chainQueue: null
  +chainCatchCallbacks: null
  +delay: null
  +afterCommit: null
  +middleware: []
  +chained: []
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I do not know why it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but when I changed config/queue.php file from `'default' => env('QUEUE_CONNECTION', 'sync')` to  `'default' => env('QUEUE_CONNECTION', 'database')` everything started working as it should